# Search Arrow Symbol using Path in UWP

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

How to create search arrow symbol as below  using Path in UWP?

expected arrow and current arrow image are shown below respectively.
current arrow image is a little bit blurred which is developed using <FontIcon GlyPh=>

code excerpt of custom search text box control

```
    <Style TargetType="local:SendTextBox" >
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlForeground}"/> ....
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:SendTextBox">
                  <Grid  >
                    <Grid.Resources>
                      <Style x:Name="SendButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                          <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">....
...
                                                **<FontIcon x:Name="GlyphElement" FontStyle="Normal"  FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontWeight="ExtraLight"   Glyph="&#xE122;" Foreground="#BFBFBF"   FontSize="30"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>**
                                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
```

I need to replace <"FontIcon"> with <"Path"> for better clarity.I thought using  "Path"  will provide professional look as in the first figure,Or Do I need to clip the image from the original wireframe and make it transparent?

[image]

[image: expected arrow]

[image: arrow using]

Comment: Could you please tell what do you mean by using Path? It is a little confused about your real scenario and what's the expected behavior.

Comment: I have created a custom search box where the arrow is inside the textbox.currently i use  <FontIcon    Glyph="&#xE122;" > for the same,but it is a little bit blurred when increasing the font size. so I need to replace the FontIcon with some path element  eg:<Path   Data="M1084.67,540.333 L1022.75,647.625 L897.577,647.75 L835.408,540.333 L897.744,432.75 L1022.5,432.167 z" />.I do not know the data syntax for arrow now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need this if there are built-in ready-made solutions?

```xml
<SymbolIcon Symbol="Send"/>
```

[image: Send]

If you still need Path, I would advise you to find/create the desired icon in SVG and convert using https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/svg-to-uwp-xaml-converter/9p5rq15t5cwj